# Website painfully slow after migration to VPS2

Tags: plugins, hosting, shared-hosting, vps

We've recently moved from Fastcomet's Speedup plan (shared) to a more powerful one, VPS2 (also Fastcomet) because our disk space was running low.

Prior to the migration, our website [www.famagusta.news](https://www.famagusta.news) was blazing fast. The moment they moved us to a bigger plan, everything went downhill.

After the migration was completed, we've noticed the slow speed right away. We didn't install new plugins or updates, nothing that could have caused the slow speed. The only change we did, was to point the cloudflare DNS to the new IP.

We advised Fastcomet's support, which up to this moment are doing their best to pinpoint the problem, but unfortunately nothing yet.

**These are the issues:**

1- Logged in users are randomly disconnected in users from wp-admin
2- Random slow first response when loading the page. Sometimes more than 20 seconds (tested with different ISPs)
3- Famagusta.news: Can't get gtmetrix speed test since the migration. I get a "Analysis Error - The page took too long to load" It works on all other websites on server, just not this one. 
4- Since switching to the VPS, Facebook fails to pull the picture from the article. Facebook debugger says "Curl error: 28 (OPERATION_TIMEOUTED)".

At this point i'm completely lost. Any ideas?

Comment: I use fastcomet too, i had same issues, you may want to check your php.ini conf like `max_execution_time` and `max_input_vars`

Comment: Hey thank you! Are you on VPS? Can you tell me what you've got for max_execution_time and max_input_vars?

Comment: sure, have a look [here](https://xilab.co/what-are-best-wordpress-php-ini-settings/)

Answer (score 0):

Fastcomet support to the rescue!

After submitting a ticket with them, they solved everything and now my website is blazing fast once again.